# SQL - daily change in a value with business day into consideration

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

Hi I am trying to write a query that will track daily changes of a column which isn't populated on weekends/holidays.

First my data looks something like this  :

```
Date           Value
11/5/2015      10
11/6/2015      11
11/9/2015      12
11/10/2015     12
11/11/2015     11
```

so i want my query to give me result of the value change each date vs. the previous business day to return something like this:

```
Date           Change in Value since previous business day
11/5/2015       -
11/6/2015       1
11/9/2015       1
11/10/2015      0
11/11/2015      -1
```

how do i write a write a query in MS Access which tracks daily changes over a business day? Currently i have written the following which only returns daily change over a calendar day as opposed to a biz day. so it won't return anything on Mondays.

```
    SELECT A.Date, A.Value, ( A.Value - B.Value) as [Daily change]
    FROM Table as A INNER JOIN Table as B on (A.date = B.date+1)
```

=============================================================================

thanks guys I've tried all 3 suggestions but they didn't work unfortunately :( there's another column called product ID and perhaps that is why? in other words, on each day, each product ID will have their own distinct values. there is a total of 100 product IDs so on each date there are 100 different values and I would like to track daily changes (business day basis) for each of the 100 product IDs. could anyone kindly help here? :(

Answer (score 0):

It's hacky, but why not:
Join on 3 days ago also
use iif to say "if the 1 day ago diff is null then show the 3 days ago diff"

```
SELECT
  A.Date, A.Value,  
  iif (isNull( A.Value - B.Value), ( A.Value - C.Value), ( A.Value - B.Value)  ) as [change since last biz day]
FROM [Table] as A  
  left JOIN [Table] as B on ( A.Date = B.Date + 1  )
  left JOIN [Table] as C on ( A.Date = C.Date + 3  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I just say it many times in English and the SQL follows. You want it where B equals the maximum date that is less than A.

```
    SELECT A.Date, 
     A.Value,
     A.Value - B.Value as [Daily Change]
     FROM MyTable as A
     INNER JOIN MyTable as B 
     ON B.date = (SELECT MAX(C.date) FROM MyTable C WHERE C.Date < A.Date)
     ORDER BY A.Date
```